# Create Node for null value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have repeated values in my csv and some null values for a column. I want to create the node for null values and merge the repeated values.

My csv is as follows:

```
column_name1,column_name2
abc,sdf
def,ert
ghi,dsg
,sgws
def,ty
opq,rew
```

Comment: Okay, what's your query so far? How exactly do you want to handle the nulls (you can't MERGE on a null property), would you want only a single node for all entries with a null property in the CSV, or should this create a new blank node for them instead? Or something else?

Comment: should create a new blank node for all null values present in csv

Comment: So if there are 5 rows with a null for column_name1, you want to do something like...create 5 new nodes with a particular label and no properties? I'm having trouble seeing the big picture of why that's useful. Please, add more information about what you're really trying to do here. Without context we're likely to miss opportunities to provide advice that's tailored for your use case, and worse we may give you advice that seems okay, but really doesn't make sense in your particular use case. The more context you can provide the better.

Comment: As in column_name1 there are 6 values out of which 1  value is null and 'def' is twice.So I want to create  5 nodes as abc,def,ghi,opq and one node for null value. Each node will have properties  and null node will have property as {type:'No Data'}.
The repeated node should get merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create two nodes per row, one per column (let's say we're using labels :Node1 and :Node2) you would use MERGE to merge the node by an indexed property, and use `coalsesce()` to supply a default for any null encountered. Due to usage of MERGE, any repeated values would match to any existing node with that value previously created.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file://import.csv' as row
MERGE (n1:Node1 {type: coalesce(row.column_name1, 'No Data')})
MERGE (n2:Node2 {type: coalesce(row.column_name2, 'No Data')})
...
```

Remember to add your index or unique constraint on :Node1(type) and :Node2(type) (or rather the equivalent for your model).